# Activator.CreateInstance with param - constructor of child class type not found

Tags: c#, .net, activator

I try to pass connectionString to context factory constructor, but got a error "constructor type of ContextImplementationTest not found" What is the problem?
I'm calling

```
string bid="someCOnnectionString";
using (BaseContext<DbContext> db = MediaDbContext.GetBidContext(bid)){...}


public static class MediaDbContext
{
   public static BaseContext<DbContext> GetBidContext(string connString)
    {
        //Settings.ContextFactory="ContextImplementationTest"
        Type contextFactoryType = Type.GetType("Media.DB.Context.Implementation." + Settings.ContextFactory);
        object[] args = new object[] { connString};
        BaseContext<DbContext> instance = (BaseContext<DbContext>)Activator.CreateInstance(contextFactoryType, args);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Base Class**

```
public class BaseContext<TContext> : DbContext where TContext : DbContext
{
    static BaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);
    }

    protected BaseContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }...
```

**Child class**

```
public class ContextImplementationTest : BaseContext<DbContext>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {...}
```

Update: to call constructor in child class, you need to have constructor in this class.

**Child class**

```
public class ContextImplementationTest : BaseContext<DbContext>
{
   protected ContextImplementationTest(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {
   }...
```

Comment: You probably need to retrieve the non public constructor info using reflection + BindingFlags, I don't think Activator sees the non public ones

Comment: You need to show us the constructor of the child class. `Activator` is looking into these constructors so they are essential to answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he47tyc4(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `nonPublic` parameter only in the case of default constructor invocation.

You can use [Type.GetConstructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6w8akb(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Type contextFactoryType = 
    Type.GetType("Media.DB.Context.Implementation." + Settings.ContextFactory);

ConstructorInfo ci = contextFactoryType .GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
    binder: null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, modifiers: null);

object[] args = new object[] { connString };

var instance = (BaseContext<DbContext> instance)ci.Invoke(args);
return instance;
```

Comment: Your answer is inaccurate: `Activator` will not find *any* non-public constructor, including the default one (you can check it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhUgxf)). Another issue with your answer is the recommendation to invoke the private constructor. Apart from failing in a limited trust environment (an issue that might or might not be important for the OP), the preferred way to avoid issues with encapsulation is to make the constructors public. Plus, how would the implementer control which constructors are supposed to be called and which not (in the case of many signatures allowed)?

Comment: @Sefe I'm referring to the `CreateInstance` overload taking a `nonPublic` parameter, not the one that only takes a type. Your fiddle code runs fine from VS/.net4.6.1 if you add `true` to the arguments (`CreateInstance(typeof(A), true)`. Concerning your remark about invoking a protected constructor, I'm not looking for a long term solution, merely answering a technical question.

Comment: @vc 74  it is works, but i also was needed to define constructor in child class 
`protected ContextImplementationTest(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }`